# A way to identify and monitor WCF api users or systems

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, authentication, monitoring

I have a this use case and i don't know what the standard way of dealing with it is.

So basicly we have a WCF based API and multiple partners/company's and their users.
Business now wants to know who or what is calling which methods and how much.
Basically they would like to monitor this. 
Also they would like to restrict the amount of calls some users or system can do if necessary.

I was thinking in terms of multiple endpoints, role based authentication and some kind of self made or wcf  performance counter to achieve this.
But this really does not seem like a standard way of doing things, so any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: This is quite an expansive topic.  One way would be claims based authentication, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is what i did.

I implemented a custom application token [SoapHeader].
And then validated it with a WCF IMessageinspector.
After that i logged the user +  token + action  in a log file witch off course i could turn off or on.
Next i plan to analyse the results of the log file together with the standard WCF perfmon counters.